# How do websites like Imgur, Google, Facebook manage so many separate webservers?

Tags: apache, networking, web, load-balancing

My question is, do websites like Imgur manually setup there webservers for loadbalancing.

Because we can assume that even a small site like Imgur will have about 50-100 webservers.

Are they all setup and managed manually, or can they use software which can automatically expand them

Answer (score 0):

They use a CDN to transfer data these servers are inter connected they share data by placing these servers in multiple region the website loads faster because of the CDN and because there inner connection is much faster